# PHP-FPM process is taking too much CPU

Tags: php-fpm, top

I'm trying to understand the `top` command, `php-fpm` is taking too much %cpu but the CPU on top is always very low
[image]

why is that happening, and where to start to maybe tune it?

Comment: You can see the meaning of that information with man top.

Comment: How have you determined that this is too much %cpu?